# Tilde in markdown doc in Sublime3 causes next blank line to be red

Tags: sublimetext3

If you open a new blank file in Sublime 3, type a line with a tilde, and follow it by a blank line, then go to View|Syntax and select Markdown, the blank line will be highlighted in red as shown below. Is this a bug or is one not supposed to use tildes in Markdown (do they have some special meaning?). This also happens for Rmarkdown docs (they knit to PDFs just fine, btw, with unescaped tildes).

[image]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The markdown syntax that ships with Sublime uses GFM (GitHub Flavoured Markdown), and in that spec the `~` character can be used for both code blocks as well as strike through text.

So in this case the reason for the red highlight is that the syntax thinks you've forgotten to close the strike through region.

You can resolve the issue by quoting the tilde, such as `I have about \~10 donuts.`, which will mark the `\~` as a markdown escape character and tell the syntax what you intended.

Comment: Hi, I did try `\~` but it didn't seem to work (see the third example in the screenshot).

Comment: What build of Sublime are you sing? In the build I'm using (latest dev build) I don't see the same result as that. Possibly there are fixes in the latest version of the syntax not available in your verison.

Comment: It says 3.1.1, build 3176

Comment: I can confirm your result using that build. This looks like a [known issue](https://github.com/sublimehq/Packages/issues/1677) that was fixed 9 days ago (as of time of this writing), is present in the latest dev builds and will be "official" in the next Stable release of Sublime.

Comment: Aha. Thanks! Good to know.

Comment: Thanks to your great explanation this question also (incidentally) answers *What does the tilda mean in markdown*, which is what I was googling for. Thank you!